# insertar enum java en mysql

Tags: java, mysql, enum

Tengo una clase Pelicula

```
public class Pelicula{
private String titulo, director, sinopsis;
private int anyo;
private Genero genero;

public Pelicula(){ /*vacio*/}

public Pelicula(String titulo, String director,  int anyo, String sinopsis, Genero genero) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.director = director;
    this.sinopsis = sinopsis;
    this.anyo = anyo;
    this.genero = genero;
}public Genero getGenero() {
    return genero;
}public void setGenero(Genero genero) {
    this.genero = genero;
}
```

En otra clase obtengo bien el enum con el siguiente codigo

`pelicula.setGenero(Genero.valueOf(getObjMarco().getDialog1().getpCPelicula().getTxtGenero().getText().toUpperCase()));`

Después tengo el código mysql

```
CREATE TABLE genero(
ID TINYINT not null auto_increment,
NOMBRE VARCHAR(30)NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
FECHA_VALIDACION TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY(ID))ENGINE=INNODB;

 INSERT INTO genero(NOMBRE) VALUES ('COMEDIA'),('ACCION'),('TERROR'),('CIENCIA_FICCION'),('THRILLER'),('SUSPENSE'),('DRAMA');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pelicula(ID SMALLINT UNIQUE NOT NULL auto_increment,TITULO varchar(70) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',DIRECTOR varchar(70) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',ANYO SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,SINOPSIS VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',GENERO TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,FECHA_VALIDACION TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY(ID),CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(GENERO) REFERENCES genero(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)engine=innoDB;
```

Tengo problemas porque no me gustaría cambiar el codigo de Pelicula de java, ni tampoco el de mysql. Como podeis ver en mysql no utilizo un valor enum. Pero además el conteo del enum en java empieza en 0 y en mysql empieza en 1. Osea, por ejemplo, obtengo genero.DRAMA en java, que es 6, y me gustaría ingresarlo en mysql como 7.
Gracias de antemano. un saludo a todos.

Comment: De que enum hablas? igual, no deberias tener un enum, ya que tenes una tabla. Cargas esa tabla en una lista en un objeto y listo...

Comment: No entiendo tu comentario. Gracias

Comment: El Enum es Genero en java

Comment: No deberias tener Genero como un enum. Bajo ninguna circunstancia.. si mañana queres agregar otro, tenes que recompilar? ademas, tu sistema no lo va a usar nunca como enum, siempre va a usar el id que viene de la tabla pelicual, que se conecta con el id del genero en la base de datos, para que queres el enum?

Answer (score 0):

Como bien dice @gbianchi, es un gravísimo error intentar meter la propiedad `Genero` de `Pelicula` en un enum.

En primer lugar, `Genero` es una entidad en sí misma, y debe ser tratada como tal. Imagina por ejemplo que se necesite una descripción del `Genero` o que el modelo de datos se extienda, y surja una nueva entidad o lógica que agrupe varios géneros. Será harto complicado adaptar tu código en cualquiera de esos casos.

Más aún, supongamos, como suele ocurrir, que una misma película pueda pertenecer a varios géneros ... Comprenderás que el haber optado por un enum no es otra cosa que capar tus datos.

Tienes dos opciones, y eso ya dependerá de otros asuntos contextuales que no vienen al caso aquí:

### Opción 1:

Declarar `Genero` como una propiedad de `Pelicula`. Y en ese caso, cuando creas la instancia de `Pelicula` debes pasar una instancia de `Genero`.

Esta sería la clase para tu entidad `Pelicula`:

```
 public class Pelicula {
    private String titulo, director, sinopsis;
    private int anyo;
    private Genero genero;

    public Pelicula(){ /*vacio*/}

    public Pelicula(String titulo, String director,  int anyo, String sinopsis, Genero genero) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.director = director;
        this.sinopsis = sinopsis;
        this.anyo = anyo;
        this.genero = genero;
    }
     
     public Genero getGenero() {
         return genero;
     }

     @Override
     public String toString(){
         return String.format("Título: %s\nDirector: %s\nSinopsis: %s\nAño: %d\nGénero:\t %s",
             titulo, director, sinopsis, anyo, genero.toString());
     }
}
```

Y esta sería la clase para la entidad `Genero`:

```
 public class Genero {
    private int idGenero;
    private String description;
    
    public Genero (int idGenero, String description) {
        this.idGenero=idGenero;
        this.description=description;
    }
    
    public int getIdGenero() {
        return idGenero;
    }
    
    public void setIdGenero(int idGenero) {
        this.idGenero = idGenero;
    }
    
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
         return String.format("Id: %d Descripción: %s",
             idGenero, description);
    }      
}
```

En este modelo de datos, la instancia de `Pelicula` tendría que construirse así:

```
    Pelicula mPelicula=new Pelicula("Un Titulo", "Un Director", 2021, "Una sinopsis", new Genero(1, "Este es el Género 1, cuya característica es..."));
    Genero mGenero=mPelicula.getGenero();
    System.out.println(mPelicula.toString());
```

**Salida:**

```
Título: Un Titulo
Director: Un Director
Sinopsis: Una sinopsis
Año: 2021
Género:  Id: 1 Descripción: Este es el Género 1, cuya característica es...
```

### Opción 2:

Declarar la propiedad `Genero` solamente por su id en `Pelicula`:

```
 class Pelicula {
    private String titulo, director, sinopsis;
    private int anyo;
    private int genero;

    public Pelicula(){ /*vacio*/}

    public Pelicula(String titulo, String director,  int anyo, String sinopsis, int genero) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.director = director;
        this.sinopsis = sinopsis;
        this.anyo = anyo;
        this.genero = genero;
    }
     
     public int getGenero() {
         return genero;
     }

    //etc
```

La instanciación se haría asi:

```
Pelicula mPelicula=new Pelicula("Un Titulo", "Un Director", 2021, "Una sinopsis", 1);
```

Y, si quieres obtener más cosas de `Genero`, como la descripción o lo que fuera, tendrás que programar código **fuera de tus clases de entidad, para no estropearlas**, donde accedas al `Genero` por su id y obtengas lo que necesites.

Lo que es importante entender aquí es que, optar por un enum no hace otra cosa que capar tus datos. En el caso de una pelicula que pueda tener más de un género, simplemente cambias la declaración de la propiedad por una lista y ya lo tienes resuelto.

Veamos el caso de la opción 1. Sólo la cambia la clase `Pelicula`, en lugar de un objeto simple `Genero`, tendremos una lista de objetos de ese tipo y en consecuencia, el método `toString()` debe adaptarse a la nueva realidad:

```
 class Pelicula {
    private String titulo, director, sinopsis;
    private int anyo;
    private List<Genero> generos;

    public Pelicula(){ /*vacio*/}

    public Pelicula(String titulo, String director,  int anyo, String sinopsis, List<Genero> generos) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.director = director;
        this.sinopsis = sinopsis;
        this.anyo = anyo;
        this.generos = generos;
    }
     
     public List<Genero> getGeneros() {
         return generos;
     }
     
     @Override
     public String toString(){
         StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
         sb.append(String.format("Título: %s\nDirector: %s\nSinopsis: %s\nAño: %d\n\nGéneros:\n",
             titulo, director, sinopsis, anyo));
         for(Genero g : generos){
             sb.append(g.toString());
             sb.append("\n");
         }
         return sb.toString();
     }
}
```

La instancia de la clase se crearía con algo así más o menos:

```
    List<Genero> generos = new ArrayList<>();
        generos.add(new Genero(1,"Este es el género 1"));
        generos.add(new Genero(8,"Este es el género 8, surgido porque bla, bla, bla"));
        generos.add(new Genero(81,"Este es el género 81, llamado así porque se relaciona con los géneros 1 y 8"));
               
    
    Pelicula mPelicula=new Pelicula("Un Titulo", "Un Director", 2021, "Una sinopsis", generos);
```

La salida de este código es:

```
Título: Un Titulo
Director: Un Director
Sinopsis: Una sinopsis
Año: 2021

Géneros:
Id: 1 Descripción: Este es el género 1
Id: 8 Descripción: Este es el género 8, surgido porque bla, bla, bla
Id: 81 Descripción: Este es el género 81, llamado así porque se relaciona con los géneros 1 y 8
```

Y en `Genero` nada ha cambiado.

Como podrás ver, el uso de un enum te hará cuesta arriba todo esto. En cuanto a la opción 1 o la opción 2, eso depende de ti, del contexto en el que estás y de lo que quieres lograr. Lo que sí te aconsejo es que pienses en grande cuando programas. Es decir, aunque ahora tus películas sean de un solo `Genero`, declara una lista, así, sólo tendrás que agregar nuevos elementos si algún día tu aplicación evoluciona.

Answer (score 0):

Primero, agradecer las explicaciones de  gbianchi y A. Cedano por magníficas y que voy a estudiar.
Al mismo tiempo hoy he encontrado una solución que me ha funcionado pero que quizás como decís vosotros después me falla.
Por a explicar mi solución. Ha sido simple, he creado un método en la clase película

```
public int convertirGeneroAEntero(Genero genere){
    int intGenero=0;
    if(genere==Genero.COMEDIA){
        intGenero=1;
    }else if(genere==Genero.ACCION){
        intGenero=2;
    }else if(genere==Genero.TERROR){
        intGenero=3;
    }else if(genere==Genero.CIENCIA_FICCION){
        intGenero=4;
    }else if(genere==Genero.THRILLER){
        intGenero=5;
    }else if(genere==Genero.SUSPENSE){
        intGenero=6;
    }else if(genere==Genero.DRAMA){
        intGenero=7;
    }
   return intGenero;
}
```

y que he utilizado en la conexión:

```
public void create(Pelicula p) {
    con=new ConexionMysql();
    int genero=p.convertirGeneroAEntero(p.getGenero());
    String instruccionSql="CALL pa_insertPelicula_01('"+p.getTitulo()+"', '"
            +p.getDirector()+"', '"+p.getAnyo()+"', '"+p.getSinopsis()+"', '"
            +genero+"')"; ......
```

Así pues, muchas gracias. Un saludo a todos.